# Run-time error on SQL UPDATE in VBA

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I am trying to make some code, which updates a row, if the item already exists. It looks like this:

```
updateStr = "UPDATE platinum_paste SET ([aluminium], [calcium], [chrome], [iron], [lead], [silicon], [zirconium]) VALUES (" & aluminium & "," & _
                                                                                                                              calcium & "," & _
                                                                                                                              chrome & "," & _
                                                                                                                              iron & "," & _
                                                                                                                              lead & "," & _
                                                                                                                              silicon & "," & _
                                                                                                                              zirconium & _
                                                                                                                              ") WHERE [lot_number] = " & lotNumber

Debug.Print updateStr

If MsgBox("Item already exists. Do you want to update its details?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
            objMyConn.Execute updateStr, dbFailOnError

Else
            'Do nothing

End If
```

When I try to run it, clicking "Yes" in the MsgBox will result in an error:

> Run-time error '-2147217900 (80040e14)':
>
> Automation error

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?I have tried to add all possible debug functions I can think of. The database connection works fine for `SELECT` and `INSERT`. This is my `INSERT` string, which works just fine:

```
insertStr = "INSERT INTO platinum_paste ([lot_number], [aluminium], [calcium], [chrome], [iron], [lead], [silicon], [zirconium]) VALUES (" & lotNumber & "," & _
                                                                                                                                                 aluminium & "," & _
                                                                                                                                                 calcium & "," & _
                                                                                                                                                 chrome & "," & _
                                                                                                                                                 iron & "," & _
                                                                                                                                                 lead & "," & _
                                                                                                                                                 silicon & "," & _
                                                                                                                                                 zirconium & ")"
```

Comment: You should use parameterized queries instead of dumping user input directly in the query string.  That will probably fix your problem.

Comment: I will try to look into that, however it still does not explain why my method does not work... It is almost identical to my `INSERT` string, which works just fine.

Comment: When you say it is 'almost identical' what are the differences?

Comment: Added to OP for comparison.

Comment: your update syntax looks weird. you are sure thats correct?

Comment: Can you paste in what `Debug.Print` gives you?

Comment: See answer from Verzweifler below...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Syntax of your `UPDATE`-String is wrong. You need to write

```
 UPDATE table_name
 SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
 WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

For further information, have a look at
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Comment: Wow, seems obvious now. Clearly, I need more coffee.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Not used to working much with `UPDATE` in SQL. I still don't get why none of my Debug attempts gave me anything useful...?

Comment: The `Debug.Print`-Messages I see in your code just print out the SQL String. They can't test its usefullness...